# Temperatures from different sources

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have two different probes monitoring the same area for temperature. I've had M loggers but I want to see if V loggers are reading the same temperature. What kind of test would I do if I wanted to know if there is a statistical difference between the data from V to M. I want to verify that V is just as accurate as M. I have a large population size (> 1400 data points for each) and I want to know if the temperatures differ by that much at a given time across a huge set of data.

Comment: Do you have paired points?

Comment: Population size here seems to mean _sample size_, What you have is the sample; what you might have is the population.

Comment: Whenever there is an expectation that measurements should be the same, plotting difference (here M $-$ V) versus mean (here (M $+$ V)/2) is a good idea and may  be more informative than any reduction of the data.

Comment: What is the goal of this? Are you trying to find sonething out about the 2 probes/measurement tools (are they well calibrated, estimate measurement noise,...)  Or are you trying to learn sthg about temperature in the area?  If the latter then there are much mor interesting\insightful things you can do than a hypothesis test (e.g., dimension reduction, blind source separation, causal (network) models to see which station influences which, ...)

Answer (score 3):

You have asked three different questions, perhaps without realizing that you have:

1) Are the two probes getting different results?

2) Are they equally accurate?

3) Are they getting the same results?

Assuming that the data is paired (which is implied by "measuring the same area") then for 1) you could use a paired t-test (or a nonparametric version). For 2) It's not clear what you would do unless you have some "gold standard", but you might look at the variance of each probe (if the temperature ought to be constant). For 3) you could use an equivalence test, most likely TOST (two one sided t tests).